# AWK, count the frequency of machine names in mutiple log files

Tags: bash, shell, logging, awk

I have log files at least 100G.
The log file directory structure like this：

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 griyn griyn 4096 Jul  2 14:33 lcdc-0615-00.log
drwxrwxr-x 2 griyn griyn 4096 Jun 29 14:22 lcdc-0615-01.log
drwxrwxr-x 2 griyn griyn 4096 Jun 28 21:25 lcdc-0615-02.log
drwxrwxr-x 2 griyn griyn 4096 Jun 28 21:25 lcdc-0615-03.log
drwxrwxr-x 2 griyn griyn 4096 Jun 28 21:25 lcdc-0615-04.log
drwxrwxr-x 2 griyn griyn 4096 Jun 28 21:25 lcdc-0615-05.log
drwxrwxr-x 2 griyn griyn 4096 Jun 28 21:25 lcdc-0615-06.log
```

And in each directory,

```
[griyn@cp01-vm-griyn test_data]$ cd lcdc-0615-00.log/
[griyn@cp01-vm-griyn lcdc-0615-00.log]$ ll
total 361216
-rw-rw-r-- 1 griyn griyn 184936785 Jun 28 21:19 yq01-spi-mx0.yq01
-rw-rw-r-- 1 griyn griyn 184936680 Jun 28 21:20 yq01-spi-mx22.yq01
```

log file content here,

```
  1 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
  2 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
  3 peer_addr[yq01-ps-beehive-agent3677:29082]
  4 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
  5 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
  6 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
  7 peer_addr[yq01-ps-beehive-agent3677:29082]
  8 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
  9 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
 10 peer_addr[yq01-ps-beehive-agent3677:29082]
 11 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
 12 peer_addr[yq01-ps-beehive-agent3677:29082]
 13 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
 14 peer_addr[yq01-ps-beehive-agent3677:29082]
 15 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
 16 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
 17 peer_addr[yq01-ps-beehive-agent3677:29082]
 18 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
 19 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
 20 peer_addr[yq01-ps-beehive-agent3677:29082]
 21 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
 22 peer_addr[yq01-ps-beehive-agent3677:29082]
 23 peer_addr[yq01-spi-mx38:29129]
```

I want to count the frequency of machine names in mutiple log files by shell script. 
I use AWK like this:

```
awk -F'[]:[]' '/peer_addr/{map[$2]+=1} END{for(key in map) {sum+=map[key];printf("%-15s %s\n", key, map[key]);} print "sum:",sum}' ${log_file_dir}/${log_path} >> ./conclusion/sum.log &
```

Apparently, we need a map structure to save and update the result. Then I have the problem that the map structure in AWK just be used in self AWK. I can not sum the result in multiple log files.

My temporary solution is, use AWK to output each log file's result to one file and then use AWK once again by that file to sum the result.

Do you have more efficient approach？

Comment: You can pass all log files to the same Awk program and it will accumulate the result over multiple files. So you do `awk '{...}' <file1> <file2> <file3> ...`.

Comment: Thank you! One problem is that there are too many files. I will try it right now.

Comment: Please define "too many"

Comment: In reality, I have thousands of log files to count the frequency of machine names. So the AWK file parameter may be too many.

Comment: Consider using **GNU Parallel** to process your files in parallel and then aggregate the results at the end.

Comment: It doesn't appear to matter which file the machine names are found in, does it? So you could just aggregate all files together into `awk` with `find ... exec cat {} \; | awk ...`

Comment: Thank you. I will learn GNU Parallel. It seems more efficient.

Comment: Griyn did you try @MarkSetchell's suggestion of find+cat? Seems sensible to me (but use `exec cat {} +` if your find supports it for efficiency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a large number of files, much larger then the max allowed argument list, then you can use Awk in the following way :

1. Create a file with all your files you want to process.

   ```
   $ find <logroot> -type f -iname '*.yq01' > <logroot>/logfiles.txt
   ```
2. Use awk to create your `ARGV` list itself:

   ```
   $ awk -F'[]:[]' '(NR==FNR){ARGV[ARGC++]=$0; next}
                    /peer_addr/{map[$2]++}
                    END{ for(key in map) {
                            sum+=map[key];
                            printf("%-15s %s\n", key, map[key]);
                         }
                         print "sum:",sum }
                   ' <logroot>/logfiles.txt
   ```

> **`ARGC`:** The number of elements in the `ARGV` array.
>
> **`ARGV`:** An array of command line arguments, excluding options and the program argument, numbered from zero to `ARGC-1`.
>   **The arguments in `ARGV` can be modified or added to; `ARGC` can be altered.** As each input file ends, awk shall treat the next non-null element of `ARGV`, up to the current value of `ARGC-1`, inclusive, as the name of the next input file. Thus, setting an element of `ARGV` to null means that it shall not be treated as an input file. The name `'-'` indicates the standard input. If an argument matches the format of an assignment operand, this argument shall be treated as an assignment rather than a file argument.
>
> <sub>**Source: [awk POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)**</sub>

**parallel processing:**

If you want to do some parallel processing, you might be interested in [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html):

```
$ cat <logroot>/logfiles.txt              \
   | parallel --jobs 4 ./process_files.sh \
   | awk '{map[$1]+=$2}
          END{ for(key in map) {
                  sum+=map[key];
                  printf("%-15s %s\n", key, map[key]);
               }
               print "sum:",sum
             }'
```

with `process_files.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
awk -F'[]:[]' '(NR==FNR){ARGV[ARGC++]=$0; next}
               /peer_addr/{map[$2]++}
               END{ for(key in map) {
                      sum+=map[key];
                      printf("%-15s %s\n", key, map[key]);
                    }}' "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. Of course it is serially executed. It is too slow to complete mission. Parallel execution is more batter.

Comment: Log files totally be at least 100G.

Comment: @Griyn Also take into account that hard disks don't do parallel read/write. Obviously, with a read buffer and tuning its size based on the number of parallel processes, you might find an optimum.

Comment: @Griyn I wrote a verson using **GNU parallel**, this could probably be improved. If you have to do this one a single time, I suggest to let it run and write the output to a single file so you can reprocess it later on whitout having to process the 100GB all over again.

Comment: "take into account that hard disks don't do parallel read/write" -- You are right, I ignored this point.